# Android how to solve open failed:ENOENT(No such file or directory) error?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an option to backup the `SQLite Database` of my app by using following code snippet.

```
 File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
                        File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "LatLng Recorder");
                        if (!myDir.exists()) {
                            myDir.mkdir();
                        }
                        FileChannel source = null;
                        FileChannel destination = null;
                        String currentDbPath = "/data/" + "com.realtech.latlngrecorder" + "/databases/" + "latLngDB";
                        String backupPath = "/LatLng Recorder/latLngDB.db";

                        File currentDb = new File(data, currentDbPath);
                        File backupDb = new File(sd, backupPath);
                        try {
                            source = new FileInputStream(currentDb).getChannel();
                            destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDb).getChannel();
                            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
                            source.close();
                            destination.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

It previously worked fine but whenever I tried to backup the Database it shows the following error.
`/data/data/com.realtech.latlngrecorder/databases/latLngDb:open failed: ENOENT(No such file or directory)`
I don't know what went wrong now. Above code worked very well previously. Any Solutions. Thank you.

Comment: if you are using emulator, check what is the name of your 'db'. Is it 'latLngDB' or 'latLngDB.sqlite' or 'latLngDB.db', probable reason is that the  db file you are looking for does not exist.

Comment: I'm using mobile device

Comment: how are you creating the database? is it with the same name?

Comment: I can not see why this is happening, but what I would try is, I would install the app on emulator, then I would try to open this DB using command prompt or file explorer if my file even exists or not. If not, it is solved if exists, then I would look for other reasons, give it a try.

Comment: i found out the error the database is not created when i tried to export it. that's the problem. Thanks for your time mate.